# window.location is opening in same tab as well as new tab how to stop this

Tags: javascript

window.location is opening in same tab as well as new tab how to stop this

I am getting the issue where i want to open the url in the same window same tab. other places is working fine in my application but one place it is getting open two times. One in the same tab and one in new tab. Is there any way I can  prevent it. Tested in IE Mozile and Chrome
Version 83.0.4103.116.

Here is my code.

```
buttonHandle : function(config){
        if(config.action == "openUrl"){
            debugger;
            window.location = window.origin + config.url;
        } 
        
    },
```

Tried multiple places in internet but no luck.

Comment: Can you include the HTML element which triggers this handler ? If you are using a link, you may be actually opening it as well.

Comment: That code, all else being equal, won't have the effect you describe. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Seblor Ya in html i am getting taret as ''_blank" is there way where i can set the targe in window.location

Comment: @David Then the bihavior you have currently is normal. setting the target as `_blank` will open the page in an other tab. You can read more in the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @Seblor Is there anyway i can make this dynamiclly in function.